# How do I properly normalize object?

Tags: typescript

I have response with `User` object from the backend, which contains property `birthday` and it is `typeof string`, but I want to convert it to `typeof Date` (e.g normalize the data).

Here is the snippet:

```js
interface User {
  username: string
  birthday: Date
}

function normalizeUser(user: Omit<User, 'birthday'> & { birthday: string }): User {}
```

How to do it properly in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
type Patch<T, Props> = Omit<T, keyof Props> & Props;

type User = {
    hello: string;
    whatever: number;
    birthdayReal: Date;
    birthdayPublic: Date;
}

declare function convertDate(s: string): Date;

function normalizeUser(user: Patch<User, { birthdayReal: string, birthdayPublic: string }>): User {
    const birthdayReal = convertDate(user.birthdayReal);
    const birthdayPublic = convertDate(user.birthdayPublic);
    const result: User = { ...user, birthdayReal, birthdayPublic };

    return result;
}
```

Check this solution [on Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAxgCwDwBUA0sBOB7MAZwD4oBeKAeQFsBLYDbAawhDwDNcCSoAyLogG4AUMNCQoAVUIQc5KAG9hUFVGQQANhrwAuKIWA5aAOwDmI1VADuyBBABusvcYCu1AEayLq97RzBkABM4EAAlCDgNPQARO28VX38gkJgXdw1aRBi44QBfUUCIRA04HGh2F2NEYFo8YyhEOsd-WOAIAApCPQMjMwBKbLaRYQqqmrqoYzwcakjaAC8IaVl2lxkcPXgkNGWcbAUoRIDgsIio-UMTU2wj5JBU9Mzuy7MoXOIBqXXFZVVG4wMhz8xxC4Ui8n+zWArQ6a1kADpbicwRo+vEGnVAUiUmkMogIU1ZNC7Kt1ojgXcHni0b8VP9AWVCC4NMA9Lt5Ad4Vy4XsgUlkWcbhSTlTMm9hpYysAXDh6ozmcARPkgA).

`convertDate` is an arbitrary function that can convert string into Date according to your rules - in your real code it shouldn't be `declare`d, but rather has to be implemented.